# Why only can store 2 cookies in IE11, Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I writing a html page run from `file://` (not use webserver), i want store some data in cookies.

I use this tool to test http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/, IE11, Edge can store 180 cookies.

But my code , i only can store 2 cookies:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {           
           var i=0;
           var name="testlimit";
           var iMax=5000;
           var val="";
           for(var i=0;i<iMax;i++)
           {
              val +="a";
           }
           for(i=0;i<10;i++)
           {
                setCookie(name+i,val,1)          
                val=getCookie(name+i);
                if(val ==null)
                {
                    alert(i);
                    break;
                }
           }
           alert(i);
          
        }   
        //Save Info to cookies
        function setCookie(name, value, days) {
            var expires = "";
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        //Get infor from cookies
        function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="test limit" onclick="test(); return false;" />   
</body>
</html >
```

Why only can store 2 cookies in IE11, Edge?

And after occur error, i can't store by cookies, i have to clear cache of browers to can store again.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: It not occur error, after set , i get value again , it is null. My sample it will stop i=2

Comment: I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: My Problem: I only can store 2 cookies in IE11, Edge. Can i store more than 2 cookies?

Comment: Is this problem present in other browsers as well?

Comment: i only using cookies in IE & Edge, because they not support local storage when run from file://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had understood my problem:

```
Max Size Per Domain= 10234 characters.
```

Because my value is 5000 characters, so i only can store 2 cookies.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already stated in your own answer, there is an overall limit per domain. Overall, I would advise against using cookies to store long texts if it is not absolutely necessary in your case. If you want to store a large amount of data in your browser, there are two recommended options:

- Local Storage (simple): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- Indexed DB (recommended for large files): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: IE or Edge : localStorge, IndexedDB not working when page run from file:// (not use webserver)